# How do I set the page viewport size using Scrapy Playwight?

Tags: python, scrapy, playwright, scrapy-playwright

I didn't find any satisfactory answer about this. All I want is just set the viewport to 1080*19200 (yes, 1920 * 10) before the request to simulate a screen of that size.

Is this even possible using Scrapy Playwright? If so, how do i do that?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of doing this:

1. In the context. Playwright's [Browser.new_context](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-browser#browser-new-context) method takes a [`viewport` argument](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-browser#browser-new-context-option-viewport), which can be used in the [`PLAYWRIGHT_CONTEXTS`](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-playwright#playwright_contexts) setting:

```py
# settings.py
PLAYWRIGHT_CONTEXTS = {
    "default": {
        "viewport": {
            "width": 19200,
            "height": 1080,
        },
    },
}
```

2. In the page. You can call [`Page.set_viewport_size`](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-page#page-set-viewport-size) from a [page init callback](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-playwright#playwright_page_init_callback):

```py
async def init_page(page, request):
    await page.set_viewport_size({"width": 19200, "height": 1080})
```

```py
yield scrapy.Request(
    url="https://example.org",
    meta={
        "playwright": True,
        "playwright_page_init_callback": init_page,
    },
)
```

3. In the page, with a [`PageMethod`](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-playwright#pagemethod-class):

```py
from scrapy_playwright.page import PageMethod
```

```py
yield scrapy.Request(
    url="https://example.org",
    meta={
        "playwright": True,
        "playwright_page_methods": [
            PageMethod("set_viewport_size", {"width": 19200, "height": 1080}),
        ],
    },
)
```